# IPhone SDK_A table view inside of a table view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to make a table view inside of a table view. I mean how can I make an app that clicking a cell goes to another list of cells to click to go subclass?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by a table view inside of a table view, I think what you want to do is have a hierarchy of table views. You can push another table view onto the stack within the delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MySecondViewController *secondController = [[MySecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
}
```

By implementing this method when you click a cell, it goes to another table view (list of cells).

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping he knew about releasing objects, but this is now perfect copy and paste code.

Answer (score 1):

Convolution's answer contains a memory leak. Proper code should look like this:

```
MySecondViewController *secondController = [[MySecondViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName: @"SecondViewController" bundle: nil];
if (secondController != nil) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: secondController animated: YES];
    [secondController release];
}
```

The `release` is essential. Otherwise you leak memory.